# Leslie matrix and stable age distribution.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working with the following data:
[Deer population](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo8wG.png)
, trying to set up a Leslie matrix that would allow me to estimate the age distribution in the group after a given number of years.

I have set it up as follows:

$L = \left[
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0.302 & 0.268 & 0.151 & 0.117 & 0.084 & 0.05 \\
 0.57 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.89 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.56 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.78 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.71 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right] , \, \, N_0 = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 33 \\
 19 \\
 18 \\
 16 \\
 9 \\
 7 \\
 5 \\
 3 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

where the top row of $L$ are the birth rates, and the diagonals the rate of survival for each age group. The vector $N_0$ represents the initial population values.

I have found the dominant eigenvalue of this system to be **0.788529**, with corresponding eigenvenctor given by:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0.455404 \\
 0.329196 \\
 0.396607 \\
 0.447644 \\
 0.31791 \\
 0.314471 \\
 0.283153 \\
 0.215454 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Then year by year, the age structure in the group is given by:

$N_1= \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 12.472 \\
 18.81 \\
 18.05 \\
 16.02 \\
 8.96 \\
 7.02 \\
 4.97 \\
 3. \\
\end{array}
\right),  N_2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 3.13467 \\
 10.7217 \\
 17.1475 \\
 14.2578 \\
 5.0176 \\
 5.4756 \\
 3.5287 \\
 1.8 \\
\end{array}
\right), N_3 = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0.849303 \\
 6.11137 \\
 16.2901 \\
 12.6894 \\
 2.80986 \\
 4.27097 \\
 2.50538 \\
 1.08 \\
\end{array}
\right)$...

I have found the **Stable Age Distribution** to be:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0.165011 \\
 0.119281 \\
 0.143707 \\
 0.162199 \\
 0.115191 \\
 0.113945 \\
 0.102598 \\
 0.0780678 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

As I understand it, this population should decay as the dominant eigenvalue is less than one.

My question I guess is, do my answers seem sensible given the data I began with? I am really out of my depth when it comes to age structured populations as I am not really sure I understand the underlying theory.

If anyone would be so kind as to point my mistakes I would appreciate it. Thank you.